# How do we describe this way of sitting?

Tags: word-request

Could someone please help me to describe this way of sitting?

[image]

Is there a single word for it?

Comment: A few words in my vocabulary that can roughly suggest this action: *squat* or *crouch*. I think it's more like a squat.

Comment: @DamkerngT. You nailed it. *Squat* is the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Squat is exactly what I was looking for. By following your suggested words I also found "hunker down". Considering that **Squat** is a term mainly used for an exercise wouldn't it better if I use **Hunker down** ?

Comment: @MaulikV My typical squat is a little different (it's not as neat as his :), so I guess that there might be a more specific word (or a few words) for it that could describe exactly what this man is doing. :)

Comment: @DamkerngT. The purpose of performing *squat* is quite clear and thus the pose is well defined. Here, the guy is not doing any yog and thus you are finding it a bit different. But, *squat* is the word.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squatting_position#Resting_position) may be relevant. I'm always amazed at Asian squatting, but I'm afraid that my flexibility (like Prandelli's) doesn't go that far.

Comment: @MaulikV: there is very rarely "only one word" for ANYTHING in English.

Comment: @CocoPop what about the word 'that'? :)

Comment: ................. it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be called **crouch**, **squat** or **stoop (down)** (although the latter can also mean to bend from the hip without bending the knees).

These all have slight nuances of meaning attached to them (at least in AmEng):

**crouch** is used when hiding from view, as when hunting or being pursued.

**squat** has two colloquial meanings: (1) to take up residence in an abandoned house or other building; (2) to defecate

**stoop** has the figurative meaning of *lowering one's standards*: I won't stoop to your level!

Comment: Thank you CocoPop. Would you also please explain "Hunker(down)"? Is it common? will you easily understand that(picture it in your mind) if you read it?

Comment: Hunker down is common in Florida, where I live, and (figuratively) refers more to gathering everything you need to survive for a few days, food, candles, water, etc. and not leaving the house. I don't think I've ever heard it in reference to squatting.

Comment: My pleasure. Great question :)

Comment: I agree with the three words, but not with the idea that crouch has only a special meaning. It is used in the everyday generic sense to indicate this posture. Also, squat is an exercise, but the other two words are not.

Comment: I only meant that to be one possible meaning, aside from the posture in the picture.